# Is there any way to call servlet from JSP page without using <form> <action> tags?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

First, I am not submitting any data to servlet to process. I want to show data in JSP file returned by servlet(of course! which fetches from databaseUtils since I am using MVC pattern).

So, I want to call servlet from JSP page, without using javascript. How do I do that?

Here is my project directory..

[project directory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KAnh.png)

I am trying to call "View_Accountant.java" servlet form "view_accountant.jsp" jsp file.

Comment: @BalusC Your answer solved my problem to some extent. when I am running the servlet alone it fetches the data and calls JSP page . But, how do I call that servlet using href? you haven't answered this question.

Comment: It's answered in the duplicate. Just use the URL of the servlet instead of the URL of the JSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use AJAX and JavaScript then you can call servlet first, set data calculated in servlet as request or session attributes and redirect to JSP. And in JSP extract data from request or session and show it or process it somehow.

Comment: fine. I have servlet which fetches data, set attribute to request object and it forwards data to JSP like "rd2.forward(request,response);" It's showing the data, when I'm running this servlet alone works fine. But how do I trigger this servlet using href?